# Fix indent on closing try catch in php mode in Emacs

Tags: php, emacs, elisp, indentation

In php mode I have try catch (when it's global - no function)

```
try {
    throw new Exception("Hello");
} catch(Exception $e) {

  }
```

the indentation put two spaces (even indent is 4 spaces), I have a function that fix it using this:

```lisp
(defun unindent-closure ()
  (message "%s" c-syntactic-context) ; debug
  (let ((syntax (mapcar 'car c-syntactic-context)))
    (if (and (member 'arglist-cont-nonempty syntax)
             (or
              (member 'statement-block-intro syntax)
              (member 'brace-list-intro syntax)
              (member 'brace-list-close syntax)
              (member 'block-close syntax)))
        (save-excursion
          (beginning-of-line)
          (delete-char (* (count 'arglist-cont-nonempty syntax)
                          c-basic-offset)))
      (if (member 'defun-close syntax)
          (save-excursion
            (beginning-of-line)
            ;; top level try cache have two extra spaces before closing braces
            (if (looking-at "^ \\{2\\}[^ ]")
                (progn
                  (beginning-of-line)
                  (delete-char 2))))))))

(add-hook 'php-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (add-hook 'c-special-indent-hook 'unindent-closure)))
```

it also fix closures indentations, it work fine when I have 4 spaces as indent but fail on this, when I have 2 spaces:

```
class foo extends Controler {
  function foo() {
}
}
```

in both cases syntax is `defun-close` (on closing curly brase). Is there other way to fix 2 spaces in try catch in php mode?